# Editing attribute saved with .build

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im trying to edit a field so that it goes in the database as the owner boolean being set to true when the user creates the account. I get the error undefined method `owner

```
= form_for @school do |f|
  = f.label :school_name, "School Name"
  = f.text_field :school_name, :class => 'form-control'
  = f.label :latitude, "Latitude"
  = f.text_field :latitude, :class => 'form-control'
  = f.label :longitude, "Longitude"
  = f.text_field :longitude, :class => 'form-control'
  = f.label :radius, "Radius"
  = f.text_field :radius, :class => 'form-control'
  = f.fields_for :admins do |ff|
    = ff.label :email
    = ff.text_field :email, :class => 'form-control'
    = ff.label :password
    = ff.password_field :password, :class => 'form-control'
    = ff.label :password_confirmation
    = ff.password_field :password_confirmation, :class => 'form-control'
  = f.submit :class => 'submit-button'
```

```
def new
  @school = School.new
  @school.admins.build
  @school.admins.owner = true
end

def create
  @school = School.new(school_params)

  if @school.save
    redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => @school
  else
    render 'new'
  end
```

Comment: Please post the complete error message

Comment: When you type Admin.attribute_names in a Rails console, what does it return?

Comment: ["id", "email", "encrypted_password", "reset_password_token", "reset_password_sent_at", "remember_created_at", "sign_in_count", "current_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_ip", "last_sign_in_ip", "created_at", "updated_at", "school_id", "owner"]

Answer (score 0):

Because `@school.admins` is a collection of multiple admins, so it doesn't have the `owner` method, that exists on the individual admin objects within that collection.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `@school.admins.build` it returns a new instance of Admin, but you're not doing anything with that instance. You need to put it in a variable, and then assign a value to its `owner` attribute. That will look like this:

```
@school = School.new
@admin = @school.admins.build
@admin.owner = true
```

But the `build` method takes an attributes argument, so you can shorten that to this:

```
@school = School.new
@admin = @school.admins.build(owner: true)
```

Don't forget that you'll also need to save this object at some point.

Comment: @admin = @school.admins.build(owner: true) didnt work

Comment: The words "It didn't work" don't actually give me any information I could use to help solve the problem. In what way did it not work?

Comment: the owner field didnt update everything else saved like normal